# Optimize Apply to create an list of string with Boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I must check to a boolean value in rows, get the name of the columns to build a list and create a new column with this list of strings.

I have this code, it works perfectly but it's very slow (I used 125 000 rows for 20 columns). Do you have an idea to optimize this code?

```
import pandas as pd 

def exlusions(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
        reasons = [name for name in x.index if x[name] == True]
        return ",".join(reasons)

dct_data = {
    'A' : [False, False, True, False, True, False],
    'B' : [False, False, False,False, False, False],
    'C' : [False, True, False,False, False, False],
    'D' : [False, False, True, False, False, False],
    'Client' : ['Paul', 'Nick', 'Josh', 'Flo', 'Julia', 'Lucia']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct_data)
df = df[list(df.select_dtypes(include='bool').columns) + ['Client']]
df = df[df[list(df.select_dtypes(include='bool').columns)].any(1)]
df['Exclusions'] = df.apply(lambda x: exlusions(x), axis=1)

df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with the columns and [`str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) the extra comma:

```
# Boolean Columns
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes == 'bool']
# Filter DataFrame rows
df = df[df[cols].any(axis=1)]
# Take dot product (multiply then sum rows) and remove trailing comma
df['Exclusions'] = df[cols].dot(cols + ',').str.rstrip(',')
```

`df`:

```
       A      B      C      D Client Exclusions
1  False  False   True  False   Nick          C
2   True  False  False   True   Josh        A,D
4   True  False  False  False  Julia          A
```